# JQUERY fade between 2 divs and loop function?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery document ready function to try and fade bewtween 2 divs on a loop. The function should have a time out / delay so that it starts after 5 seconds after the page loading and then every 5 seconds after that it should fade between the 2 divs constantly.

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong, thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showpanel() {
        $(".switch_up").fadeOut("slow");
        $(".switch_up2").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    setTimeout(showpanel, 5000);
    $(".switch_up2").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".switch_up").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you need to use `.fadeToggle()` to alternate between fading in and out.

Second, you should use `setInterval` which runs in intervals of specified amount of time instead of `setTimeout` which only runs once.

```js
$(function(){
    //this sets an infinite timer that launches the function after
    //5 seconds, and keeps doing it every 5 seconds infinitely.
    setInterval(TogglePanels,5000);
});

function TogglePanels(){
    var $first;
    var $second;
    //check which one is visible, to fade it out first:
    if($(".switch_up").is(":visible")){
      $first=$(".switch_up");
      $second=$(".switch_up2");
    }else{
      $first=$(".switch_up2");
      $second=$(".switch_up");
    }
  
   //fade out the visible panel
   $first.fadeToggle("slow",function(){
       //this is a callback function that runs when the fading is complete.
       //fade in the invisible panel
        $second.fadeToggle("slow");
   }); 
   
}
```

```css
.switch_up{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
.switch_up2{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch_up"></div>
<div class="switch_up2"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of **fadeToggle()** instead of using fadeIn() and fadeOut() separately for each div and create a *setTimeOut loop* using *recursion*.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  timeout();

  function timeout() {
     $(".switch_up").fadeToggle("slow");
     setTimeout(function () {
         $(".switch_up2").fadeToggle("slow");
         timeout();
     }, 5000);
} 
});
</script>
```

Here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/enGKqyDjcda6v5xOHKfS?p=preview)

Cheers!

Comment: thanks but this causes the 1st div to fade out straight away as soon as the page loads. I want a 5 second delay before the first div fades out then fade in the 2nd div straight away for 5 seconds and then fade the 2nd div out again and the 1st div back in. this should continue on an infinite loop. any ideas?

Comment: You can add the css property "display:block" for the div you want to see first. Updated the Plunker. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: thanks this is nearly there however i don't want the two divs to crossfade with each other, i want div 1 to completely fade out before div 2 fades in and vice versa. thanks

Comment: @JamesDaley you are welcomed to check my answer, which does exactly that.